# How to PubSub from non-streaming Dataflow

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I want to notify to GAE when DataFlow job is finished.

So, I tries to make the following pipeline:

```
from apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub import WriteStringsToPubSub

  (
      p | ReadFromDatastore(google_cloud_options.project, query)
...snip...
      | 'send to pubsub' >> WriteStringsToPubSub(GCS_TOPIC)
  )
```

But the above code produces the following error:

> ValueError: PubSubPayloadSink is currently available for use only in streaming pipelines.

How to notify the GAE app when job is finished?
Should I use the `GCPClinentLibrary`?
(from google.cloud import pubsub_v1)

Comment: I think you should consider this [link](https://github.com/amygdala/gae-dataflow) for examples on how to run Cloud Dataflow pipelines from App Engine apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to deploy your code using a Pcollection representation for your pipeline. 
Pubsub messaging (as you did using PubsubIO). is one of the ways to communicate with the GAE. Please follow [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/pubsub-io) to get more details. A simple code could be as follows:

```
  // streamData is Unbounded.
  PCollection<String> streamData = ...;
  streamData.apply(PubsubIO.Write.named("WriteToPubsub")
                       .topic("/topics/my-topic"));
```

The python code also can be written as follows (pcol has to be placed after all the stes including ptransform and Pardo, etc):

```
from apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub import WriteStringsToPubSub
pcoll = (p
             | ReadStringsFromPubSub('projects/fakeprj/topics/baz')
             | beam.Map(lambda x: x))
             | WriteStringsToPubSub('projects/fakeprj/topics/a_topic')
```

For more details please review [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/pubsub_test.py).

Please note that the pipeline also can be run from your GAE python application. Thus, you need to just add a notifier command after the following lines (To make sure that the job is finished and wait_until_finish() function can be used.
  ):

```
  results = p.run()
  result.wait_until_finish()
```

You can also use the grpc. For more details, please read [here](https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/python.html).

AMQP protocols such as RabbitMQ and ZeroMQ python client codes also can be used.

Comment: Is It Stream Pipeline? I want to batch Pipeline and publish message.

Comment: PCollection is implemented in the pipeline either batch or stream). Above code should work for batch and stream modes

Comment: I don't believe this code was tested. Currently you'll generate an exception if you try and use `WriteStringsToPubSub` with `--streaming=False`.